# Can I adjust this query to only show the relevant locale?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a query that

```
SELECT c
FROM c 
join locales in c.locales
WHERE locales.country = 'SE' AND
locales.language = 'sv' AND
locales.categories[0] = 'Dam'
```

I am trying to adjust it to only display the relevant locale as specified in the WHERE clause so I tried adjusting it to:

```
SELECT c.locales[0]
FROM c 
join locales in c.locales
WHERE locales.country = 'SE' AND
locales.language = 'sv' AND
locales.categories[0] = 'Dam'
```

But that does not help since it might not be locales[0], I had assumed that the join would make the relevant part of the array always appear as index [0] but I was wrong

How can I adjust the query to show the entire document but only the relevant part in the locales array?

**Please note I want the entire document shown but only with the relevant locale from that array.**

The documents looks as below:

```
{
    "id": "0570eca0-8f16-4c85-a985-e3a271bcc6bc",
    "_id": "5b07c2bfbc7407000122e8b4",
    "artno": "0614460008",
    "vendor": "Acme",
    "updatedAt": "2019-06-25T18:50:33.167Z",
    "locales": [
        {
            "title": "Gestreiftes T-Shirt",
            "description": "Gestreiftes T-Shirt aus Baumwolljersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Herren",
                "Große Größen",
                "T-Shirts & Tanktops",
                "T-Shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                ],
            "country": "DE",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "language": "de",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008005",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008002",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008004",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008006",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008003",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Striped T-shirt",
            "description": "Striped T-shirt in cotton jersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Men",
                "T-shirts & Vests",
                "Short Sleeve",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                   ],
            "country": "UK",
            "currency": "GBP",
            "language": "en",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008006",
                    "urls": [
                        ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008005",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008004",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008002",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008003",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Randig t-shirt",
            "description": "En randig t-shirt i bomullstrikå.",
            "categories": [
                "Herr",
                "T-shirts & Linnen",
                "Kortärmat",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                 ],
            "country": "SE",
            "currency": "SEK",
            "language": "sv",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Striped T-shirt",
            "description": "Striped T-shirt in cotton jersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Men",
                "T-shirts & Tank tops",
                "Short Sleeves",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                  ],
            "country": "US",
            "currency": "USD",
            "language": "en",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "relatedArtno": [
        "0614460001",
        "0614460002",
        "0614460005",
        "0614460006",
        "0614460007",
        "0614460011",
        "0614460012"
    ],
    "_rid": "QEwcAMCVWqgGAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/QEwcAA==/colls/QEwcAMCVWqg=/docs/QEwcAMCVWqgGAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"2e00f1ca-0000-0c00-0000-5d144d660000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1561611622
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a full document sample so we can help you with local tests?

Comment: Done and please note I would like the output to be the entire document but all non relevant locales removed from the locales array so that it only shows the one relevant locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt. According to your description, i think you could make a slight change as below:

```
SELECT locales
FROM c 
join locales in c.locales
WHERE locales.country = 'SE' AND
locales.language = 'sv' AND
locales.categories[0] = 'Herr'
```

Output:

[image]

---

Update sql:

```
SELECT c.id,c.artno,c.XXX(what properties you want),.....
,locales
FROM c 
join locales in c.locales
WHERE locales.country = 'SE' AND
locales.language = 'sv' AND
locales.categories[0] = 'Herr'
```

Comment: Yes but I still need the entire document not only the locale, I want to show the entire document but only with the relevant locale in that array as oppose to all of them, your solution shows only the relevant locale not the entire document as well